# C Disassembly - Function Preamble on windows with Visual Studio

Tags: c, windows, assembly, parameters, disassembly

I created the following C library so I can look through the assembly and learn more about it by practical examples.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "paramtest.h"
    
__int64 test(__int64 a, __int64 b) {
    __int64 c = 3;
    return a + b + c;
}
```

After I created the dll in Visual Studio (debug mode without Optimizations) I used x64 dbg to take a look at the generated assembly. Here I find however a few unexpected instructions that I cannot really explain to me.

```
00007FFD29B91690 | 48:895424 10             | mov qword ptr ss:[rsp+10],rdx                              | Source.cpp:5
00007FFD29B91695 | 48:894C24 08             | mov qword ptr ss:[rsp+8],rcx                               |
00007FFD29B9169A | 55                       | push rbp                                                   |
00007FFD29B9169B | 57                       | push rdi                                                   |
00007FFD29B9169C | 48:81EC E8000000         | sub rsp,E8                                                 |
00007FFD29B916A3 | 48:8BEC                  | mov rbp,rsp                                                |
00007FFD29B916A6 | 48:C745 08 03000000      | mov qword ptr ss:[rbp+8],3                                 | Source.cpp:6
00007FFD29B916AE | 48:8B85 08010000         | mov rax,qword ptr ss:[rbp+108]                             | Source.cpp:7, rax:__enc$textbss$end+A
00007FFD29B916B5 | 48:8B8D 00010000         | mov rcx,qword ptr ss:[rbp+100]                             |
00007FFD29B916BC | 48:03C8                  | add rcx,rax                                                | rax:__enc$textbss$end+A
00007FFD29B916BF | 48:8BC1                  | mov rax,rcx                                                | rax:__enc$textbss$end+A
00007FFD29B916C2 | 48:0345 08               | add rax,qword ptr ss:[rbp+8]                               | rax:__enc$textbss$end+A
00007FFD29B916C6 | 48:8DA5 E8000000         | lea rsp,qword ptr ss:[rbp+E8]                              | Source.cpp:8
00007FFD29B916CD | 5F                       | pop rdi                                                    |
00007FFD29B916CE | 5D                       | pop rbp                                                    |
00007FFD29B916CF | C3                       | ret                                                        |
```

1. Why do we push the 2 parameters that the function requires onto the stack, especially, on stack+0x08 and stack+0x10 even tho this could overwrite values of the calling function? Shouldn't local variables be **below** the stack pointer, since everything above it belongs to the calling functions stack frame?
2. Normally the preamble I see is `push rbp -- mov rbp, rsp`. How come that we do subtract from the stack pointer before we set the basepointer? In my assembly the rbp would point to the lower point of this functions stack where I would have learned it should point to the uppermost section?
3. Any reason why we save `rdi`? Or is this just because its unoptimized code and it followed a "better safe then sorry approach"?

Comment: In general it's pointless to look at unoptimized code. Anyway the calling convention mandates 4 stack slots of shadow space for the specific purpose of storing the arguments if needed.

Comment: "the calling convention mandates 4 stack slots of shadow space"

So, theoretically I should decrease rsp before calling any function to stay true to the convention?

Comment: Yes, you need to ensure that space is available in case the called function relies on it.

Comment: There's more information than you'd ever want to know about windows x64 calling conventions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/x64-calling-convention?view=msvc-170).  There's all sorts of little tidbits tucked away in there: *The stack pointer must remain 16-byte aligned in any region of code that isn't part of an epilog or prolog, except within leaf functions.*

Comment: The only push/pop in this code are save/restore of call-preserved registers, not pushing args.  MSVC debug mode isn't just un-optimized, it does stuff like poisoning uninitialized stack space.  But that's not happening here, it just looks extremely inefficient and reserving a huge amount of stack space for no apparent reason.  Can't reproduce on https://godbolt.org/z/a7MT5rGnr - but maybe your IDE project settings include some extra compiler options.